# How to cancel tab change in WPF TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have found multiple questions about this problem on SO, however I still can't quite get a realiable solution. Here is what I came up with after reading the answers.

Xaml:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300" x:Name="this">
    <TabControl IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs, ElementName=this}" x:Name="TabControl"/>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var tabs = new ObservableCollection<string> {"Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3"};
        Tabs = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(tabs);
        Tabs.CurrentChanging += OnCurrentChanging;
        Tabs.CurrentChanged += OnCurrentChanged;
        Tabs.MoveCurrentToFirst();
        CurrentTab = tabs.First();
    }

    private void OnCurrentChanging(object sender, CurrentChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        //only show message box when tab is changed by user input
        if (!_cancelTabChange)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Change tab?", "Message", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.No)
            {
                _cancelTabChange = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        _cancelTabChange = false;
    }

    private void OnCurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_cancelTabChange)
        {
            //Update current tab property, if user did not cancel transition
            CurrentTab = (string)Tabs.CurrentItem;
        }
        else
        {
            //navigate back to current tab otherwise
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Tabs.MoveCurrentTo(CurrentTab)));
        }
    }

    public string CurrentTab { get; set; }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TabsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Tabs", typeof(ICollectionView), typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(ICollectionView)));
    public ICollectionView Tabs
    {
        get { return (ICollectionView)GetValue(TabsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TabsProperty, value); }
    }

    private bool _cancelTabChange;
}
```

Basically I want to display a confirmation message, when user navigates to different tab, and if he clicks "no" - abort the transition. This code does not work though. If you click multiple times on "Tab2", each time choosing "no" in message box, at some point it stops working: events stop triggering. Event will trigger again if you click on "Tab3", but if you choose "yes" it opens second tab and not third. I am having trouble figuring out wtf is going on. :)

Does anyone see a bug in my solution? Or is there an easier way to display a confirmation message, when user switches tabs? I am also willing to use any opensource tab control, which does have a proper `SelectionChanging` event. I could not find any though.

I am using .Net 4.0.

**Edit:**
If I comment the message box out:

```cs
private void OnCurrentChanging(object sender, CurrentChangingEventArgs e)
{
    //only show message box when tab is changed by user input
    if (!_cancelTabChange)
    {
        //if (MessageBox.Show("Change tab?", "Message", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.No)
        //{
            Debug.WriteLine("Canceled");
            _cancelTabChange = true;
            return;
        //}
    }
    _cancelTabChange = false;
}
```

Everything works fine. Weird.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys, this does not take into account the fact, that user can navigate tabs using keyboard. Also i do not want to disable tabs completely. If user selects "yes" in a message box, he should still be able to change tab normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution from [web.archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210120155559/http://coderelief.net/2011/11/07/fixing-issynchronizedwithcurrentitem-and-icollectionview-cancel-bug-with-an-attached-property/)

seems to work quite well with

```
<TabControl ... yournamespace:SelectorAttachedProperties.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItemFixEnabled="True" .../>

private void OnCurrentChanging(object sender, CurrentChangingEventArgs e)
{                   
    if (MessageBox.Show("Change tab?", "Message", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;                    
    }                     
}



public static class SelectorAttachedProperties
{
    private static Type _ownerType = typeof(SelectorAttachedProperties);
 
    #region IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItemFixEnabled
 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItemFixEnabledProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItemFixEnabled", typeof(bool), _ownerType,
        new PropertyMetadata(false, OnIsSynchronizedWithCurrentItemFixEnabledChanged));
 
    public static bool GetIsSynchronizedWithCurrentItemFixEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItemFixEnabledProperty);
    }
 
    public static void SetIsSynchronizedWithCurrentItemFixEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItemFixEnabledProperty, value);
    }
 
    private static void OnIsSynchronizedWithCurrentItemFixEnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Selector selector = d as Selector;
        if (selector == null || !(e.OldValue is bool && e.NewValue is bool) || e.OldValue == e.NewValue)
            return;
 
        bool enforceCurrentItemSync = (bool)e.NewValue;
        ICollectionView collectionView = null;
 
        EventHandler itemsSourceChangedHandler = null;
        itemsSourceChangedHandler = delegate
        {
            collectionView = selector.ItemsSource as ICollectionView;
            if (collectionView == null)
                collectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(selector);
        };
 
        SelectionChangedEventHandler selectionChangedHanlder = null;
        selectionChangedHanlder = delegate
        {
            if (collectionView == null)
                return;
 
            if (selector.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem == true && selector.SelectedItem != collectionView.CurrentItem)
            {
                selector.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = false;
                selector.SelectedItem = collectionView.CurrentItem;
                selector.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true;
            }
        };
 
        if (enforceCurrentItemSync)
        {
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(selector)["ItemsSource"].AddValueChanged(selector, itemsSourceChangedHandler);
            selector.SelectionChanged += selectionChangedHanlder;
        }
        else
        {
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(selector)["ItemsSource"].RemoveValueChanged(selector, itemsSourceChangedHandler);
            selector.SelectionChanged -= selectionChangedHanlder;
        }
    }
 
    #endregion IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItemFixEnabled
}
```

Comment: Wow, thats... complex. I have tried setting `e.Cancel = true;` before, but I gave up on it after I have noticed, that it does not affect the selected tab. I'll try using this "fix", thx. :)

Comment: *nods* but at least it's set-and-forget :)

Answer (score 2):

For some reason adding TabControl.Focus() fixes things:

```
private void OnCurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!_cancelTabChange)
    {
        //Update current tab property, if user did not cancel transition
        CurrentTab = (string)Tabs.CurrentItem;
    }
    else
    {
        //navigate back to current tab otherwise
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
        {
            Tabs.MoveCurrentTo(CurrentTab);
            TabControl.Focus();
        }));
    }
}
```

I still have no clue what on Earth is going on here. So I will gladly accept the answer, which sheds some light on this issue.

Comment: Using this method with the rest of your code worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

inside the tabControl_SelectionChanged  event handler:

```
if (e.OriginalSource == tabControl) //if this event fired from your tabControl
            {
                e.Handled = true;

                if (!forbiddenPage.IsSelected)  //User leaving the tab
                {
                    if (forbiddenTest())
                    {
                        forbiddenPage.IsSelected = true;
                        MessageBox.Show("you must not leave this page");
                    }
             }
```

Note that setting forbiddenPage.IsSelected = true causes a loop and you reenter
this event handler.  This time, however, we exit because the page selected IS the forbidden page.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void MainTabControl_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ReasonBecauseLeaveTabItemIsForbidden)
        {
            if (MainTabControl.SelectedIndex == IndexOfTabItem)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(SomeMessageWhyLeaveTabItemIsForbidden);
            }
            MainTabControl.SelectedIndex = IndexOfTabItem;
        }
    }
```

IndexOfTabItem - index of TabItem that disabled for leaving.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution in ViewModel, with a property bound to `TabControll.SelectedItem`. In the setter do change the value, but using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` change it back and raise that has been changed, then View accept change back...

```
private int selectedTabIndex;
public int SelectedTabIndex {
    get => selectedTabIndex;
    set {
        var oldValue = selectedTabIndex;
        selectedTabIndex = value;
        if(!TabCanBeChanged(value)) {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new Action(() => {
                    selectedTabIndex = oldValue;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedTabIndex));
                })
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

xaml:

```
<TabControl PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="TabControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
```

Code behind:

```
private void TabControl_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;
    MyVM vm = tabControl.DataContext as MyVM;

    // Cancel Tab Changed if Save failed
    if (e.Source is TabItem && !vm.Save())
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

He who must be obeyed requested that the application ask the user if they wish to leave the page so here is the slightly changed code:

```
    private Object _selectedTab;

    public Object SelectedTab
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedTab;
        }
        set
        {
            if (
                  !(_selectedTab is ADR_Scanner.ViewModel.ConfigurationViewModel) || 
                  !_configurationViewModel.HasChanged ||
                  (System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to leave this page without saving the configuration changes", ADR_Scanner.App.Current.MainWindow.Title, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                )
            {
                _selectedTab = value;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTab");
        }
    }
```

I think this small change does pretty much what you wanted.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the below answer. I have verified that the tab change can't be prevented from the VM without using a timer to switch it back.

Answer (score -2):

There is a much easier solution. Add a binding to the selected item in the XAML:

```
    <TabControl SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}" ...
```

Then in the view model:

```
    private Object _selectedTab;

    public Object SelectedTab
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedTab;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedTab is ADR_Scanner.ViewModel.ConfigurationViewModel && _configurationViewModel.HasChanged)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Please save the configuration changes", ADR_Scanner.App.ResourceAssembly.GetName().Name, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                _selectedTab = value;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTab");
        }
    }
```

Obviously you replace ADR_Scanner.ViewModel.ConfigurationViewModel with your own view model class. Lastly make sure you initialise _selectedTab in your constructor otherwise the TabControl will have no initial selection.

Comment: Well, no. I wish it was that easy. Your code prevents `_selectedTab` from being changed, but that's pretty much all it does. It does not affect UI in any way and therefore does not solve this problem.

Comment: No, it prevents the user changing the tab when not appropriate. This is the same as cancelling the tab change. It solved the problem I had.

Comment: Can you explain why and how it should work? Because I know for a fact, that in order for this binding to trigger, `SelectedItem` (and therefore selected tab) should already be changed. It works the same way with all the other bindings: you can not prevent UI property from changing from view model level. You can only set it back to previous value using dispatcher if you want to, but you do not do that either.

Comment: Why have you given me -1 when I have solved your problem? :(

Comment: "Can you explain why and how it should work? " The code is copied from my application and it works. Please try it. I use .Net 4.5 on Windows 10.

Comment: I tried it before down-voting. It does not work in both .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5.2, that is why there is so many weird and complex workarounds to this problem on SO: you can't solve this by a simple binding.

Comment: Then explain why it works in my application? This is the full Tab control attribute list: 

       <TabControl x:Name="MyTabControl" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}" Margin="4" 
                    Background="#DCE8F3"
                    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                    SelectedIndex="0"
                    BorderBrush="LightGray"
                    TabStripPlacement="Top"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">

Comment: How can I explain why it works in your application without seeing your source code? You are the only one who can do the explaining. That being said, if your application is open source, you can link it here (or email the link to me) and I will take a look. Or you can create a small project that demonstrates your approach in action and link that instead. I did it myself, but as I said, it does not work (not when I do it anyway) and I don't see why it should.

Comment: Or we can just agree to disagree. :) If your approach is good, you will get upvoted in no time.

Comment: "Or you can create a small project that demonstrates your approach in action and link that instead. " I could spend lots of my time explaining this to you, but given your ungrateful attitude, I cannot be bothered.